# Сборка gcc cross-toolchain

Tags: linux, gcc

Мне нужно собрать GNU gcc tool-chain чтобы затем с его помощью собрать Linux систему для ARM желательно из под chroot. Я внимательно изучил документацию на gcc, glibc. И я не понял из нее как это правильно делается. Читал "Cross Linux From Scratch", но там не то, что мне нужно и главное там по шагам описано что делать, но не описано почему все делается именно так, а не иначе.

В Интернете есть руководства, но в них также не описана логика сборки.
Мне не понятно:

1. Какие пакеты нужно собирать из искходников кроме binutils, glibc и gcc.
2. Во всех исполнимых файлах в секции `.interpeter` стоит путь в каталог, в котором я собираю (`/opt/cross/usr/lib/ld-linux.so`). Но я хочу пользоваться toolchain из sysroot. Будет ли тогда он работать и если нет, что делать?

Comment: Buildroot - это дистрибутив, распространяемый в исходниках, там всё уже написано и сделано.

Comment: Я знаю о нем. Но я хотел детально разобраться в процессе установки. Я собираюсь использовать Linux в коммерческом проекте. Опыт меню уже научил, что с Linux нужно разобраться до мелочей во всем, или есть вероятность оказаться в ситуации, когда что-то не работает и непонятно, что делать.

Comment: `путь в кактало` – каталог же? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Мне нужно собрать GNU gcc tool-chain чтобы затем с его помощью собрать
>   Linux систему для ARM

Это две разные задачи:

1. Собрать кросс-тул
2. Собрать программу для ARM

Если Вас интересует именно второй пункт, то проще всего ничего не собирать самому. В составе многих дистрибутивов Linux есть набор кросс-тул для большинства платформ. Лично я (работаю на бубунте) использую кросс-пакеты для Power-PC:

1. gcc-5-powerpc-linux-gnu
2. g++-5-powerpc-linux-gnu
3. binutils-powerpc-linux-gnu

Всё великолепно собирается, загружается на целевую платформу и исполняется там.

Я использую сМаке и для создания ELF-файла использую такую методу:

```
# Создаём каталог для построения ELF в каталоге проекта
mkdir build_for_powerPC
cd build_for_powerPC

# Указываем тулчейн для кросскомпиляции                                                     
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../powerPC-toolchain 

# Собственно сборка
make -j3
```

Файл powerPC-toolchain, расположеный в каталоге проекта, содержит информацию
о кросс-тулзах:

```
SET( CMAKE_C_COMPILER   powerpc-linux-gnu-gcc )
SET( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER powerpc-linux-gnu-g++ )
SET( CMAKE_STRIP powerpc-linux-gnu-strip )
SET( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MinSizeRel )
SET( CROSS true )
add_definitions( -DCROSS )
```

Для ARM всё совершенно аналогично, только кросс-пакеты надо установить:

1. gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabih
2. g++-5-arm-linux-gnueabihf
3. binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf

**Замечание:** Имена бинарников в кросс-тулзах и моём файле powerPC-toolchain несколько различаются. Я это сделал специально. Что бы не было проблем, Вы можете либо создать символические линки в каталоге /usr/bin, либо ппрописать "правильные" имена бинарников в этот файл.

Если же Вас итересует именно процесс создания кросс-тулзов, то рекомендую воспользоваться пакетом Crosstool-NG. Там всё довольно подробно описано и весь процесс создания кросс-тулзов отлажен.

Comment: Странные у вас названия бинарников, подавляющее большинство программ заточено под шаблон **$(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc** и тому подобные.

Comment: Спасибо.Попробую crosstool-ng. Мне нужно собирать систему не только для ARM но и для x86. Я никак не мог понять, как так собрать cross-tools, чтобы собрать свои библиотеки(glibc, glib2 и др) и затем чтобы cross-tools брал только эти библиотеки, не из основной системы. Есть 4 параметры --build, --target, --host, --sysroot. Я пытался разобраться как с ними работать, но пока не понял.

Comment: **чтобы cross-tools брал только эти библиотеки** - ключик --sysroot и служит именно для этой цели.

Comment: **Попробую crosstool-ng.** Да, настоятельно рекомендую. Я даже делал перевод руководства  по crosstool-ng,ну для себя. Если интересно - можете глянуть: http://disk.tom.ru/c8cbfx6 Вот только за качество перевода - не взыщите! :-)

Comment: @Sergey Я знаю о ключе --sysroot, но у меня он почему-то не работает. Я не смог разобраться почему. gcc 6.3.1

Comment: @OlegGavrilchenko пожалуйста, опубликуйте вопрос про `--sysroot` как отдельный вопрос. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: @Nick Volynkin я не могу сформулировать вопрос про --sysroot. Мне слишком многое не понятно.

Answer (score 0):

> Я знаю о ключе --sysroot, но у меня он почему-то не работает.

Вот пример, как я собирал плагин для gStreamer под ARM с использованием этого ключа:

```
SRC_C = gstmultifile.c  gstmultifilesink.c  gstmultifilesrc.c  gstsplitfilesrc.c  patternspec.c
SRC_H = gstmultifilesink.h  gstmultifilesrc.h  gstsplitfilesrc.h  patternspec.h                

GCC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc                                                                    

GLIB_FLAGS =                                                                                   
GSTR_FLAGS = -lgstcontroller-1.0 -lgstbase-1.0 -lgstreamer-1.0                                 
LIBPATH += -L/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib                                          


all: $(SRC_C) $(SRC_H)                                                                         
        $(GCC) -DHAVE_CONFIG_H --sysroot=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot $(SRC_C) $(GSTR_FLAGS
) -shared -fPIC -lgobject-2.0 $(GLIB_FLAGS) -o libmultyfile.so
```

Comment: Если это просто дополнение к ответу, то есть смысл добавить его в ваш исходный ответ, а не публиковать ещё один.

Comment: **Если это просто дополнение к ответу** - нет, это ответ на другой вопрос, прозвучавший в комментарии, Так как этот мой ответ содержит исходный текст, то решил его оформить именно как ответ, а не как комментарий.

Comment: А, вот что. Если есть другой вопрос — то для начала его стоит опубликовать как отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Иначе структура нарушается, у нас же тут строгое правило: один вопрос в теме. К тому же, гораздо менее вероятно, что человек, у которого тоже не работает `--sysroot`, будет искать ответ в вопросе с названием "Сборка gcc cross-toolchain".